# Python multiple substring index in string

Tags: python, string, loops

Given the following list of sub-strings:

```
sub = ['ABC', 'VC', 'KI']
```

is there a way to get the index of these sub-string in the following string if they exist?

```
s = 'ABDDDABCTYYYYVCIIII'
```

so far I have tried:

```
for i in re.finditer('VC', s):
  print(i.start, i.end)
```

However, re.finditer does not take multiple arguments.

thanks

Comment: Python strings have a built-in *find()* function. Use that

Comment: @Pingu `find()` returns only the first substring index, they seem to need all of matches.

Comment: @bereal So? If find returns >= 0 just try again at an appropriate offset

Answer (score 2):

You can join those patterns together using `|`:

```
import re
sub = ['ABC', 'VC', 'KI']
s = 'ABDDDABCTYYYYVCIIII'

r = '|'.join(re.escape(s) for s in sub)
for i in re.finditer(r, s):
    print(i.start(), i.end())
```

Answer (score 1):

A substring may occur more than once in the main string (although it doesn't in the sample data). One could use a generator based around a string's built-in *find()* function like this:

**note the source string has been modified to demonstrate repetition**

```
sub = ['ABC', 'VC', 'KI']
s = 'ABCDDABCTYYYYVCIIII'

def find(s, sub):
    for _sub in sub:
        offset = 0
        while (idx := s[offset:].find(_sub)) >= 0:
            yield _sub, idx + offset
            offset += idx + 1

for ss, start in find(s, sub):
    print(ss, start)
```

**Output:**

```
ABC 0
ABC 5
VC 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` over the `find` string method.

```
s = 'ABDDDABCTYYYYVCIIII'
sub = ['ABC', 'VC', 'KI']

print(*map(s.find, sub))
# Output 5 13 -1
```

Comment: using `dict(zip(sub,map(s.find, sub)))` it creates a `dict` with the substrings as keys and the indices as values.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)?

```py
s = 'ABDDDABCTYYYYVCIIII'
sub = ['ABC', 'VC', 'KI']
results = [s.find(pattern) for pattern in sub]

print(*results) # 5 13 -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with `re`, if there can be multiple indices then this might be better as the list of indices is saved for each key, when there is no index found, the substring won't be in the `dict`.

```
import re
s = 'ABDDDABCTYYYYVCIIII'
sub = ['ABC', 'VC', 'KI']

# precompile regex pattern
subpat = '|'.join(sub)
pat = re.compile(rf'({subpat})')

matches = dict()
for m in pat.finditer(s):
    # append starting index of found substring to value of matched substring
    matches.setdefault(m.group(0),[]).append(m.start()) 

print(f"{matches=}")
print(f"{'KI' in matches=}")
print(f"{matches['ABC']=}")
```

Outputs:

```
matches={'ABC': [5], 'VC': [13]}
'KI' in matches=False
matches['ABC']=[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use String index  Method

```
list_ = ['ABC', 'VC', 'KI']

s = 'ABDDDABCTYYYYVCIIII'


for i in list_:
    if i in s:
        print(s.index(i))
```